# Spotify API callback to Vue frontend gives error on Flask backend

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, spotify

I'm working on a small website using a Flask backend (running on localhost:5000), Vue frontend (running on localhost:8080) and various 3rd party APIs, most notably [Spotify](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/). I use the [spotipy package](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/) and a Flask backend to fetch the data from Spotify. As per the Spotify user authorization and the [spotipy implementation](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/#authorization-code-flow), I need to provide a callback URI for Spotify.

Here's the auth process I have:

```
oauth = SpotifyOAuth(client_id=environ.get("SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID"), client_secret=environ.get("SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET"),
                     redirect_uri="http://localhost:8100/callback", scope=scopes)
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=oauth)
```

The above has a global scope, and authorization occurs when I make a call to the Spotify API through spotipy e.g. in this endpoint and its helper method

```
@app.route('/currently-playing', methods=['GET'])
def now_playing():
   return get_currently_playing()

def get_currently_playing():
    '''
        Gets the user's currently playing track
    '''
    return jsonify(sp.current_user_playing_track())
```

which I call on the frontend like this:

```
async fetchCurrentlyPlaying() {
     let response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/currently-playing`);
```

However, the `redirect_uri` matches the callback URI I have listed for the app on my Spotify developer account. However, the callback URI matches *neither* the Flask backend nor the the Vue frontend. And, I'm not running anything on localhost:8100. When I first hit Spotify's API and it takes me to the 'Do you grant the following permissions to this app' page and I accept, I am then redirected to a new tab at http://localhost:8100/callback?code={code_here} and get this response:

[image: Spotify callback response]

The 'Close Window' button does nothing and I'm forced to reload the frontend (localhost:8080), but then all works. What I'd like is for the callback URI to be on the **Vue frontend**, e.g. localhost:8080/callback, so I can display a similar message and the redirect the user back to the home page, but if I change the callback on developer.spotify.com and the spotipy auth to this

```
oauth = SpotifyOAuth(client_id=environ.get("SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID"), client_secret=environ.get("SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET"),
                     redirect_uri="http://localhost:8080/callback", scope=scopes)

sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=oauth)
```

, then even though I have defined that route on the Vue router

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/callback",
    name: "Callback",
    component: Callback,
  },
```

I get the following error on my Flask backend:

```
File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask_cors\extension.py", line 165, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\kriel\spotify-flask\server\app.py", line 94, in now_playing
    return get_currently_playing()
  File "C:\Users\kriel\spotify-flask\server\spotipy_helper.py", line 165, in get_currently_playing
    return jsonify(sp.current_user_playing_track())
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 1169, in current_user_playing_track
    return self._get("me/player/currently-playing")
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 291, in _get
    return self._internal_call("GET", url, payload, kwargs)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 221, in _internal_call
    headers = self._auth_headers()
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\spotipy\client.py", line 212, in _auth_headers
    token = self.auth_manager.get_access_token(as_dict=False)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 484, in get_access_token
    "code": code or self.get_auth_response(),
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 439, in get_auth_response
    return self._get_auth_response_local_server(redirect_port)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 405, in _get_auth_response_local_server
    server = start_local_http_server(redirect_port)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\spotipy\oauth2.py", line 1227, in start_local_http_server
    server = HTTPServer(("127.0.0.1", port), handler)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\http\server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

even though I have this to enable CORS on the Flask backend [and don't get CORS errors otherwise]

```
# enable CORS
CORS(app, resources={r'/*': {'origins': '*'}})
```

I get this error even if I change the callbacks to localhost:5000/callback (i.e. to Flask).

How do I get around this? It's clunky and not a great user experience.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you're getting a windows socket error. Have you tried running your applications as a local administrator? Also check if there are any other processes currently bound to the socket/port by using `netstat -o`

Comment: @KrisWiniarski I just tried running as a local administrator and that didn't help unfortunately. I ran `netstat -ano -p tcp`  but didn't see anything obviously weird:
Just the processes from when I do `npm run serve` (Though I usually run through vue ui) : 

  App running at:
  - Local:   http://localhost:8080/
  - Network: http://192.168.1.220:8080/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Spotipy documentation](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.16.1/#redirect-uri):

> The redirect_uri argument or SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI environment
> variable must match the redirect URI added to your application in your
> Dashboard

Did you change the default redirect URI in your Spotify developer dashboard ?
This could be the cause of those socket errors.

Comment: I did, and the redirect URI matches the one in the Spotify developer dashboard.
Both are http://localhost:8080/callback